# How do I check/uncheck items in a ListBox with pywinauto?

Tags: listbox, pywinauto, checkedlistbox

I am trying to automate the Cambium LINKPlanner application using pywinauto, and found controls for almost everything I needed. However, there is a checked list box which has the identifier 'ListBox' and there doesn't seem to be any way to check/uncheck the items in the list.

[image: Screen shot of (checked) ListBox]

I can list the contents of the ListBox:

```
>>> app.LINKPlanner.ListBox.item_texts()
['PMP 450b High Gain', 'PMP 450b Mid-gain', 'PMP450 (retired)', 'PMP450d (retired)', 'PMP450i', 'PMP450i ATEX/HAZLOC']
```

I can highlight an item in the ListBox either by name or position:

```
>>> app.LINKPlanner.ListBox.select('PMP450i')
<win32_control.ListBoxWrapper - '', ListBox, 70154>
>>> app.LINKPlanner.ListBox.select(2)
<win32_control.ListBoxWrapper - '', ListBox, 70154>
```

But I can't check/uncheck the checkbox inside the list items.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Using Vasily's suggestion, I was able to see the bounding box, then use  click_input to click the checkbox.

```
>>> app.LINKPlanner.ListBox.select('PMP 450b High Gain').item_rect(0)
<RECT L0, T0, R276, B17>
>>> app.LINKPlanner.ListBox.select('PMP 450b High Gain').click_input(coords=(9,9))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's detected as ListBox, it may be owner-drawn check boxes which can't be detected separately. I'd suggest using method `.item_rect(item_name)` and then method `.click_input()`. Also method `.client_to_screen()` may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Vasily, that did the trick.
  app.LINKPlanner.ListBox.select('PMP 450b High Gain').click_input(coords=(9,9))
checks or unchecks the box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `.select("item text")` and `.send_keys("{SPACE}")`.

I tried Vasily's answer to use `item_rect()`. That works but it has some drawbacks.

In my case `item_rect` was not reliable: it was always 2 to 4 pixels taller than in reality.  This error adds up for consecutive items.  My script ended up clicking the wrong checkboxes.

Also, if the list is too long it requires scrolling.  This requires a separate workaround.

I found my `ListBox` would toggle the checkbox at the press of the space bar.

So I'm doing this instead:

```py
# De-select all (there is a button to do this).
dialog.window(title="Deselect all").click()

# Select the desired items.
for item in ["Item 1 name", "Item 5 name"]:
   dialog.ListBox.select(item)
   dialog.ListBox.type_keys("{SPACE}")
```